# How to enable macros for only one sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

In my excel sheet I am validating that a specific column should not be empty and its values should be unique. This validation should only be performed on "Sheet1" but it is working for other sheets also. My code is

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rngCell As Range
 Dim lngLstRow As Long
  lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
  For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow) 
  If rngCell.Value = 0 Then MsgBox ("Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell.Address) rngCell.Select
   End If 
   Next 
   End Sub
```

The second validation for unique values is done by data validation functionality in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the sheet you want the code to act on, rather than using ActiveSheet.

So, in the case that you want to check Sheet1, you would change it to this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim rngCell As Range

Dim lngLstRow As Long

lngLstRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow)
    If rngCell.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell.Address
        Sheet1.Activate
        rngCell.Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It partially works....gives me error if say any cell is empty in sheet1 but im saving the excel on sheet2. Says select method of range class failed.

Comment: Ok, please add the `Sheet1.Activate` line shown above.

Comment: It just redirects to the sheet1 but still shows the error select method if range class failed

Comment: The code doesn't create an error for me. Please edit your post with details of your data and the error, including what the value of rngCell.Address is when the error is thrown.

Comment: it worked. Tried on a fresh template.  Apparently something was wrong with the previous one.  Thanks.