# How to check for duplicate value in Excel vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Data validations in Excel are not working when user copy-pastes the data.

I want an error message to be thrown when the user pastes duplicate data in a column.

I'm using the following code(another alternative) but this is not what I want. I want this to be checked when the user inserts the data and if there is any issue then throw an error message.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 
  Dim rngCell As Range Dim lngLstRow As Long lngLstRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow) 
    If CountIf(Range("A:A"),A1) > 2 Then
      MsgBox "Please enter unique value " & rngCell.Address
        rngCell.Select
    End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: You have an open question on this topic already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable macros for only one sheet in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1568904/how-to-enable-macros-for-only-one-sheet-in-excel)

Comment: Hi, this one is different actually. Data validation are not working in excel when the user copy pastes the data. So i was wondering if there is any option if an error message could be thrown when the duplicate data gets pasted. Displaying error before save is secondary. I want error message on data insertion itself

Comment: Please review this: https://superuser.com/questions/870926/restrict-paste-into-dropdown-cells-in-excel

Comment: Denying pasting of data is not a good option especially when u have large amount of data.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your post and share what *you've* tried to solve your own problem and specify exactly what your restrictions are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `Change` event, we can trap duplicate entries without data validation:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeOfInterest As Range, Intersection As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set RangeOfInterest = Range("A:A")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(RangeOfInterest, Target)
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    With Application
        For Each cell In Intersection
            If .WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RangeOfInterest, cell.Value) > 1 Then
                .EnableEvents = False
                    .Undo
                .EnableEvents = True
                MsgBox "duplicates not allowed"
            Exit Sub
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

1. the code can handle both typed entries into column **A** as well as copy/pastes into the column
2. the code can handle multi-cell copy/pastes into the column